# How much do the internal angles of the circumferences measure, which have 3 points of tangency?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Being $A$, $B$ and $C$ points of tangency, find $x + y$.

I do not understand how to solve, since I think that $'x°'$ y $'y°$  can vary a lot, those angles can be enlarged or reduced depending on how you transcribe the drawing.

[image: Angles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$DA=DB=DC,$$ 
$$\measuredangle DAB=x$$ and $$\measuredangle DCB=y,$$
we obtain:
$$360^{\circ}-2x-2y=70^{\circ},$$ which gives
$$x+y=145^{\circ}.$$

Comment: @MichaelRozerberg Thank you

Comment: You are welcome!